# Python elementtree Getting duplicate elements from the loop when inserting subelements for a non-root node

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Using Python elementtree to try to insert subelements to a subnode using a loop but loss the root end node.

I have the following XML of argument filename=/Desktop/test.xml and pass in argument of "a,b,c"

```
<root><A></A></root>
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def get_args():
    """ Parse and return the arguments of the application """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Replace ")
    parser.add_argument('filename',
        action = 'store',
        help = '')
    parser.add_argument('s',
        action = 'store',
        help = '')
    return parser.parse_args()


def appendSS(p, ss):
    for s in ss.split(','):
        w = ET.Element("W")
        w.set("name",s)
        p.append(w)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ The starting point of the application """
    args = get_args()
    doc = ET.parse(args.filename)
    root = doc.getroot()

    appendSS(root.find("A"), args.s)
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    if tree.write(args.filename):
        print ("%s was updated successfully!" % args.filename)
    else:
        print ("failed to update %s" % args.filename)
```

Expected:

```
<root><A><W name="a"/><W name="b"/><W name="c"/></A></root>
```

Actual:

```
<root><A><W name="a"/><W name="b"/><W name="c"/></A>
```

Also getting the "failed to update `<filename>`" error message.

Comment: I get the expected output.  `tree.write` doesn't return anything, so your `if` condition will always evaluate as False.  I'd wrap `tree.write` in a try/except block instead.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the missing the  is from the "cat ". Wonder why cat will remove it? I did a tree.Dump, the  is there.